# Error with 301 Redirect and IDN Domain

Tags: .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I got a Domain called nölsch.de (xn--nlsch-jua.de in PUNYCODE) for about four years. Because of some SEO Optimizations I bought noelsch.de .

NölSch.de is located on Server A and
NoelSch.de on Server B

I placed a .htaccess on Server A with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.noelsch.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But this doesn't work for me. I tried many versions but still facing the same issue.
nölsch.de/bla-bla should be redirected to noelsch.de/bla-bla

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect a whole domain to another, you can use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead

```
Redirect / http://www.noelsch.de/
```

This redirects all URLs unchanged from server A to www.noelsch.de. When everything works as you like, you can change it to

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.noelsch.de/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked fine for me.
Don't know why my Server did not apply my htaccess..